# Unable to delete "sticky files" without using Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10

There are some "sticky files" on my Windows 10 machine which I cannot delete via Command Prompt (using `del` or even Python's `os.remove()` function). However, Windows Explorer **is able to delete them without any problem**.

I am presented with an "Access Denied" error in the command-line. But I seem to have access to those files. And in any case I get the same error even when trying to delete from an elevated command prompt.

These files are generated as part of a build process; the make file fails to clean them when I run `make clean`.

The files are not being used by any process as per Process Explorer. Restarting the machine also does not change their "sticky" status.

Comment: Can you give us more information about these un-deletable files? Do you know what program is generating them? What extension do they have?

Comment: @AruAkise loved your edit! Nice work, please keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

Guys sorry for wasting your time. The files were read-only! Using `del /f` gets rid of them from the command line.

I think I will leave this question here as a testament to my stupidity and for other absent minded folks.